# Load Tick Data in YYYYMMDD HHTTSSLLL format

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, time-format

I am trying to read a time series given as .csv file using Pandas. The data describes high frequency exchange rates and it is of the following form

```
time,bid,ask
20120401 170041033,1.204070,1.204190
20120401 170200097,1.204080,1.204200
```

where the time is to interpret as YYYYMMDD HHMMssLLL (and L = milliseconds). I try to do this using the following piece of code

```
parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%M%D %H%T%s%L')
ts = pd.read_csv('./tick.csv',
                 index_col = 'time', 
                 parse_dates = 'time', 
                 date_parser = parse)
```

which always yields the error message:

'D' is a bad directive in format '%Y%M%D %H%T%s%L'

Does somebody know where this error message comes from? I do not know why the abbreviation of D for 'day' should be incorrect.

Comment: There is no `%D` in [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). note that the directives are case sensitive.

Comment: Thats exactly the list if was looking for!